# Как в OpenGL получить цвет пикселей в текстуре?

Tags: c++, opengl

Как в OpenGL получить RGBA цвет из PNG текстуры? Загружаю с помощью stb_image.

Comment: Тут стоило бы уточнить - в каком именно месте получить. На стороне CPU или на какой-то стадии работы графического конвеера.

Comment: На стороне CPU. Нужно получить цвет пикселя или альфа канала для проверки текстурного  атласа. Есть картинка по заданным координатам или нет.

Comment: Ну там же функция загрузки возвращает указатель на массив с пикселями.

Comment: Да, и я понимаю что можно все просчитать во время загрузки, но есть возможность сделать это после? Хранить указатель и к нему обращаться?

Comment: ¿А как это еще может быть по-вашему? Чтобы смотреть содержимое изображения, его надо будет где-то хранить.

Answer (score 0):

0. Если у вас OpenGL 1.0 (в котором надо писать `glBegin()` и `glEnd()`), вы берете его двумя руками и вышвыривате на свалку истории - он безнадежно устарел.
1. Во фрагментном шейдере есть [`texture2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)), которая делает именно то что вам нужно - извлекает из текстуры цвет.

Comment: Не правильно задал вопрос. На стороне CPU. Нужно получить цвет пикселя или альфа канала для проверки текстурного  атласа. Есть картинка по заданным координатам или нет.